# Google Books in Android emulator

Tags: google-account, android-emulator, google-play-books

Has somebody been able to run Google Books in the emulator?

I've installed this app, but when I run it, the only thing I get is a "Google Accounts" - "0 accounts" banner, with the rest of the screen in black.

I've configured the e-mail in the "device" with a Google account, and it works sending and retrieving messages.

I really hope this is a noob question with a really simple answer. For the moment, I don't know what the Books app is expecting or where's it looking for that Google account.

Thanks! =)

Comment: In `Accounts and sync` there should be a list of `More accounts`, of which `Google` is an option.  Does anyone know if it's different on the simulator?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to configure the account information in **Settings -> Accounts and Sync**. That is where the "Google Account" needs to reside.